# PHPUnit WithConsecutive is gone, what is the recommended approach?

Tags: php, phpunit

PHPUnit removed withConsecutive. There are ways to workaround it to reproduce similar behaviour and I found those approaches in this site.

This question is not about a workaround or replacement - I would like to know what is the recommended approach to some situations that would seem to require this removed behaviour.

An example.

We have a Client object. This client has two methods, a getToken and a postData.

```
class MyClient {
    public function __construct(private HttpClient $client)
    {
    }

    public function getToken(): string
    {
        return $this->client->post('some-url', ['some parameters'];
    }

    public function postData(array $data, string $token = null): void
    {
        if(is_null($token))
        {
            $token = $this->getToken();
        }

        $this->client->post('some-other-url', ['token' => $token, 'some-more-params']);
    }
```

What would be the approach to mock this without `withConsecutive`?